# LiveCycle Designer - Printer Tray mapping

Tags: printing, mapping, livecycle, printer-control-language, tray

I'm trying to do so when you print from Adobe Acrobat/Reader it prints to a specific tray/bin in the printer. I just want to change the LiveCycle Design settings and not the Workbench settings.

Also, I'm sending a PDF that converts to a PCL and then prints.

So this is where I'm right now:

I created a paper type called "A4Tray3", that I can use on my Master pages.

So now I want to mapp "A4Tray3" to a specific tray/bin. I'm looking in the file "hppcl5e.xdc" and I'm trying to figure out where to write some PCL code that prints to the right tray. I have the specifics for the printer and all I need to know is where i write the mapping from the paper type to the tray for my printer.

Is it somewhere here?

```
    <!-- ========================================== -->

    <!-- OUTPUT SEQUENCES                           -->

    <!-- ========================================== -->

       <seq id="preDoc"><ESC/>%-12345X@PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY=""&#13;&#10;<var name="staple"/><var name="jog"/><seq

   use="#PJLCmd"/>@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PCL&#13;&#10;<seq

   use="#InputTrayCmd"/><seq

   use="#OutputTrayCmd"/><seq

   use="#JobSeparationCmd"/><ESC/>*t600R<ESC/>&amp;u600D</seq>
```

%-12345X@PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY=""

Regards

Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of printer trays is not applicable to PDF. **That is, you cannot specify a particular printer tray when printing a PDF document.** The selection at the printer is based on page size, and the first non-secured tray that matches the required page size is used. If no match to the size is found, a manual feed is requested.
([source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/Services/WS92d06802c76abadb-2f74688c12dbeb3d85f-7fe1.html))

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But I forgott to write that my PDF converts to PCL. 

I think it could work since I can choose  a paper type and make it print a specialtype with just a PDF. Or I'm I thinking totally wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. PCL is the standard stream of data accepted by printers. PDF is a converted version of the document and does print directly to your printer. How you convert your PDF to PCL by printing from Acrobat Reader?

Comment: I will have to reply later, cause I have to talk to the server / printer guys. They told me that my PDF converts to PCL. And I will try to clearify.

Comment: We changed direction abit, we still want to do it from the fil and not the server. But now we will use a xdp and it goes throug the server to Another print server and becomes a PCL fil.

So will I just try to write in "ESC&l4H" or should I in some fil direct my paper type "A4Tray3" to some tray?

Comment: Seems like you can't bypass this. Hopefully someone find away.